# JQuery html on a different pages

Tags: jquery, html

One of my pages is becoming overcrowded with html forms and js. So I was wondering if there is a way to have the form on one page and then the js on another. If you could refer me to a good site that addresses this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about putting the js in another HTML page or in a separate .js file?

Comment: form should be sitting on an html/php file whereas javascript on another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an excellent way.  You put your JavaScript in a file, say `/scripts/someStuff.js` off of your web root, and import it using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/someStuff.js"></script>
```

Comment: would this be able to listen to the changes on the form such are checked boxes and then hide elements?

Comment: oh, and do I need a <form action="somestuff.js">?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can reference objects in another window, if openen with the window.open method. References take the form:

window.opener.form.fieldname.value

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a test example for that 
I have a external js file named test.js that i have kept in Script folder in my root directory
I have button on my page and on its click event client side code is written in test.js file

Main page code

```
<html>
<head id="Head1">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <input id="TestButton" type="button" value="Test" />
</body>
</html>
```

External js code in Test.js file

```
$(function()
{
    $('#TestButton').click(function()
    {
        alert('I am clicked.');
    });

});
```